How to show that a differential form is not exact?
I want to show that the differential form $w = x^2\sin(y) dx \wedge dy + 2x \sqrt{1+y^4} dx \wedge dz \in \Omega(\mathbb{R}^3)$ is not exact.
Would it be enough to show that $w$ is not closed? Or does the implication only works the other way around?
The only other two ways I know are:

To show that the underlying space is not connected, which is not the case here.
To show that the integral over a closed curve is zero like in this question
Show that the form $w$ is closed but not exact
But in my case $w$ is not closed and I don't know how to transform my $w$ to polarcoordinates (if that is even helpfull here).

Thank you very much in advance!

Since exact forms are closed, yes it is enough to show $w$ is not closed.

This differential form is closed and exact.

Is it normal that the "component" $\mathrm{d}x \wedge \mathrm{d}y$ appears twice in $\omega$ ?

Sorry, the last wedge product was supposed to be $dx ∧ dz$. I think now the differential is not closed anymore.

What is your $dw,?$

@KurtG. With the "new" differential $w = x^2\sin(y) dx \wedge dy + 2x \sqrt{1+y^4} dx \wedge dz$, I have $dw = 4xy^3/\sqrt{y^4+1} \ \  dy \wedge dx \wedge dz$. The first term vanishes and in the second term only the derivitiv of dy is relevant.
